# Have a NoMethodError when trying to implement simple_calendar in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am trying to implement the gem simple_calendar into my application for a project. I am following the Github documentation (https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar) to help me through the process but I have an issue in the 'Rendering Events' section.

After running the scaffold command for single day events and making the changes to my controller and view I tried updating my calendar page and got the error 'undefined method `reject' for nil:NilClass'. It has highlighted the first line of my calendar view as having the issue but I do not know what the issue is:

```
 <%= month_calendar events: @events do |date, events| %>
  <%= date.day %>
   <% events.each do |event| %>
  <div>
   <%=event.name %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I cannot find 'reject' anywhere in my code and I'm stuck as to what to do next. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: i think your error come from [here](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar/blob/master/lib/simple_calendar/calendar.rb#L88). Do you have any events in `@events` ?

Comment: I don't have any events no, literally only worked through the documentation up until this point. Had so many issues with other solutions I was just trying to get it working first.

Answer (score 0):

Event If you do not have events do not use `events: @event` leaves only this code:

```
<%= month_calendar do |date| %>
  <%= date %>
<% end %>
```

If you have any object that you want to show change it by events